# How to validate a contents of a file using awk command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a file abc.txt with contents as :

```
8503 C
8501 C
8500 C
```

I want to validate the contents of the file in a such a way that:

For `8503` - the value has to be "C"
if yes then success
else Fail

It should repeat for all the contents in the file

ie. suppose if the file contains:

```
8503 E
8501 C
8500 C
```

Now `8503` has value as "E" then it is a failure.
8501 has value as "C" it is a success

How would I do it using shell script?

---

I tried the below command :

```
awk -F ' ' '$2 != "C" { echo "Value is not C for happy path" }' < /tmp/abc.data
```

but it gives me a blank output without the echo being displayed.

I want to see if the second column of the file has any value apart from "C" then it is a failure.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This is more a "write my program for me" request than a question about a specific problem you encountered while trying to write that program yourself. While this may or may not be homework, the guidance in [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) is pertinent -- that a good question is about a **specific problem** with your **existing implementation**. Thus, a good question shows (the smallest testable subset of) the work you did yourself, and focuses on exactly how its behavior differs from what was intended.

Comment: (See the [mcve] guidelines for more clarity on what I meant by "smallest testable subset").

Comment: ...so, adding code is a step forward, but instead of "no luck", how about describing what it actually does when it's run (with specific inputs provided in the question), and how that differs from what you want it to do?

Comment: Why do you need to use `awk`? Do you want something like `grep -Eqv " C$" /tmp/abc.txt && echo "Incorrect lines"` or `sed -n 's/.* [^C]$/Incorrect line: &/p' /tmp/abc.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to check to see if there are any values in column 2 that aren't "C" which will cause a "fail" then:

```
 awk '$2!="C"{e=1;exit}END{print e?"fail":"success"}'
```

Comment: Thank you JNevill. But it should do it for all the contents in the file. I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: It's still a bit unclear then. Is it that there should be no "E" in the file at all?

Comment: A bit more focus on prodding the OP to improve the clarity of the question and there might be less need for evolving/rewritten attempts at answers based on guessed-at interpretations. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree. However, when I wrote this it was pretty clear. Odd, but clear. I'm sticking with this edit though as I'm sick of hitting the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you with your `awk` script: your mistake is to use `echo` which is not a valid awk command. Use `print` instead:

```
awk '$2 != "C" { print "Value is not C for happy path" }' < /tmp/abc.data
```

(I removed the `-F` option which is not necessary: whitespace-separated fields is the default)

However, as stated by Walter in comment, a mere `grep` command seems to be enough in your case (with GNU `sed` here to add a header line):

```
grep E$ /tmp/abc.data | sed '1i Error lines:'
```